# How to deserialize a keyless array with GSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json, deserialization, gson

I like to use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to deserialize the following JSON String.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "id": "FSROGD.4440181",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          16.7594706041998,
          43.148716514354945
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I already prepared the neccessary Java classes named *Response*, *Features*, *Geometry* and *Coordinates*. Besides the last class everything works fine. But for *Coordinates*, I do not understand what I should write since there are no keys given that I could prepare as member variables.
Here are the parent *Geometry* class ...

```
package info.metadude.trees.model.vienna;    
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Geometry {     
    @SerializedName("type")
    public String type;

    // TODO: Prepare Coordinates class for GSON.
    // @SerializedName("coordinates")
    // public Coordinates coordinates;
}
```

... and the empty *Coordinates* class.

```
package info.metadude.trees.model.vienna;    
public class Coordinates {
    // TODO: No idea what should be defined here.
}
```

Comment: I don't think coordinates should be be a class itself, but rather just an array of doubles in the geometry class. Or you would have to provide your own serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `coordinates` as a collection property in `Geometry`. This would automatically map the values to the right property.

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GSonTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{        \"type\": \"Point\",        \"coordinates\": [          16.7594706041998,          43.148716514354945        ]      }", Geometry.class));
    }

    public static class Geometry {

        List<Float> coordinates;

        public List<Float> getCoordinates() {
            return coordinates;
        }

        public void setCoordinates(final List<Float> coordinates) {
            this.coordinates = coordinates;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Geometry [coordinates=" + coordinates + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I would go for Double since Float shortens the values. Also, as far as I understood I do not need to add getters and setters if my member is public (I use it in an Android enviroment).